# Setting up the jQuery Mobile script

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am new to jQuery mobile. I perfectly know how to reference all my scripts and CSS file. But right now I am a little bit confused on how to embeded my own code.
Take for example when coding normal jQuery we use:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   // we embedded codes here
});
```

But for jQuery Mobile I have a code which I use:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit',function (){

});
```

So I embed all my code inside.

Should all code be in the bind? I am just a little bit confused on this  or when am I suppose to embed a code inside the bind? Is it code that I want to execute when the page loads?

Also what is the difference between the mobileinit and pageinit?

Comment: Thanks Juhana for the edit. I appreciate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ## Update:
>
> ### jQuery Mobile 1.4

#### The following events are deprecated and will be removed on jQuery Mobile 1.5:

1. [`pageshow`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/)

   - Replacement: [`pagecontainershow`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show)
   - Usage: It is used to retrieve `id` of previous page.

     ```
     $(document).on("pagecontainershow", function (e, ui) {
       var previous = ui.prevPage;
     });
     ```
   - This event cant be attached to a specific *page ID*.
   - Recommendation: Use [`pagebeforeshow`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/) instead to attach event to specific pages.

     > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/YTj23/)**
2. [`pagehide`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagehide/)

   - Replacement: [`pagecontainerhide`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-hide)
   - Usage: It is used to retrieve `id` of next page.

     ```
     $(document).on("pagecontainerhide", function (e, ui) {
       var next = ui.nextPage;
     });
     ```
   - This event cant be attached to a specific *page ID*.
   - Recommendation: Use [`pagebeforehide`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforehide/) instead to attach event to specific pages.

     > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/YTj23/)**
3. [`pageinit`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/)

   - Replacement: [`pagecreate`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/)

---

> ### jQuery Mobile 1.3.2 and below
>
> <sup>*Some events are deprecated, check update*</sup>

#### Introduction:

jQuery Mobile uses Ajax navigation to load pages/views into DOM (pagecontainer), enhance (style) them and then display them on request. A page goes through many steps (page events) from the time it gets inserted into DOM until it's removed. This applies to both models, *Single-Page* and *Multi-Page*.

#### Events:

I will go through essential events and most used ones in their sequential order.

- `mobileinit`: <sup>(1)</sup>

  The very first event that fires when a website using jQM is loaded. jQM consists of many widgets that have default options. Those widgets are not initiated during that event, therefore, you can override *Global Settings* / *defaults* of those *widgets* once this event fires.

  > **Important:** Your code should go after jQuery.js and before jQM.js to successfully change defaults.

  ```
  <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
      $.mobile.page.prototype.options.theme = "b"; // set theme "b" to all pages
    });
  </script>
  <script src="jQuery-Mobile.js"></script>
  ```
- `pagebeforecreate` and `pagecreate`: <sup>(1)</sup>

  These events are almost the same. During them *widgets* auto-initialize and start enhance contents markup. They are useful to override *widget*'s defaults of a specific element(s).

  ```
  $(document).on("pagecreate", "[data-role=page]", function () {
    $(".selector").listview({ icon: "star" }); // changes list items icons to "star"
  });
  ```
- `pageinit`: <sup>(1)</sup> <sup>(4)</sup>

  This is similar to `.ready()` and it fires once per page when it's fully initialized and styled but still not viewed. Use it to bind events to that page being initialized. If you don't specify a page, you will get muliple events every time `pageinit` occurs.

  ```
  $(document).on("pageinit", "#myPage" , function () {
    $(this).on("swipeleft", function () {
     // code
    });
  });
  ```
- `pagebeforechange`: <sup>(2)</sup>

  It fires twice for a page that not has been viewed before and once for a cached/viewed page. It omits an object of data `toPage` and `options`, they contain all details related to the page that will be viewed. It's very useful to know the user came from page **X** and going to page **Y**. During this event, you can prevent the user from viewing page **Y** and take him to page **Z**.

  ```
  $(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {
    if(data.toPage[0].id == "Y") {
      $.mobile.changePage("Z");
      e.preventDefault(); // don't update $.mobile.urlHistory
    }
  });
  ```
- `pagebeforehide`: <sup>(3)</sup>

  It triggers on the current active page **X** but before page transition / animation takes place.
- `pagebeforeshow`: <sup>(3)</sup>

  It triggers on the page **Y** that will be shown after the current page but still no transition / animation.
- `pageshow`: <sup>(3)</sup> <sup>(4)</sup>

  Transition / animation is done and page **Y** is shown.
- `pagehide`: <sup>(3)</sup> <sup>(4)</sup>

  Transition / animation is done on page **X** and it's hidden.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/SjPLn/)**

---

#### Diagrams (jQM 1.4) <sup>(5)</sup>

> [image: Multi-Page Model]

---

> [image: Single Page Model]

<sup>(1) Fires once.</sup>

<sup>(2) Fires twice for new page and once for cached page.</sup>

<sup>(3) Fires whenever it occurs.</sup>

<sup>**(4) *Deprecated* as of jQM 1.4 and will be *removed* on jQM 1.5**</sup>

<sup>(5) Resource: PageContainer Events [link 1](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/) & [link 2](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/jquery-mobile-page-events-extra/)</sup>