# jQuery mobile: Links and pagechange events?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

Can somebody please clear up some of these page events methods for me: loadpage, pagebeforechange,pagechangefailded,pageload...

I understand that they are for external pages. However, I have a href links , so why do I need these events?

Can you post examples on where to attach them and what's the difference? Any good tutorials and examples will be great!

I'm using a lot of external data that I'm receiving from PHP programs on a Linux server. I'm planning to use JS functions that will call XMLHttpRequest. Should I use any page events that I mentioned before for that?

Thanks!

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457195/setting-up-the-jquery-mobile-script/20459433#20459433). Those event work for both as long as Ajax is enabled. External pages (.html) are fetched loaded into DOM via Ajax.

Comment: do you need more details/explanation?

Comment: That will be great! I'm confused as where to use it and how. Especially in my case with server. How it works with a href?

Comment: those events are to be used front-end as far as I know. As they give you control over DOM elements, loaded thru jQM Ajax navigation system. Use them to attach events to elements, change defaults, add/remove elemenets, etc...