# What is the "mobile-pagecontainer" selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile has various events and methods. The `pagecontainer` events and methods are used to handle most of the `page` events from `v1.4`. I do not understand the use of the `:mobile-pagecontainer` selector.

The API documentation only uses `$('.selector')` which is straightforward and simple to understand though, I do not know which object it is referring to. Am I supposed to use it on a `$('div[data-role="page"]')`  or on `$('body')`. And what does the other selector, `:mobile-pagecontainer`, signify?

API: [jQuery 1.4.0 API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer)

Edit: Also, I found many examples on stackoverflow and other websites using `$(document)` what is the relation to all these?

Edit 2: I created a tiny fiddle which exhibits the `pagecontainerbeforeshow` event using all the 3 selectors `$('body')`, `$(':mobile-pagecontainer')` and `$(document)`[Fiddle - PageContainer Events](http://jsfiddle.net/lordbalmung/qwNL6/5/). My heart felt gratitude and thanks to @Omar

Comment: I know, and I have knocked on his door many a times and ready to read even a 10 page document, but could not find one. @NonameBilly, kindly suggest any document if you have found any :)

Comment: Lol, I like how you phrased that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`$(":mobile-pagecontainer")` is a **selector**, it refers to the *parent* element of jQM pages, both *internal* pages and *external* ones.

By default, `:mobile-pagecontainer` is `body`. It also can be referred to as `$.mobile.pageContainer` (mind capital "C" in pageContainer).

`.pagecontainer()` is a function that is used to *change* and *load* pages, as well as retrieve *active page*.

In short, `$(":mobile-pagecontainer")` = `$.mobile.pageContainer` = `$("body")` (default).

The value of `:mobile-pagecontainer` can be overridden on `mobileinit`, in case you want to wrap pages in a different element than `body`.

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
  $.mobile.pageContainer = $("#foo");
});
```

- To change pages (assuming `foo` is the container):

  ```
  $("#foo").pagecontainer("change", "#pageID or URL");
  ```
- To load an *external* page:

  ```
  $("#foo").pagecontainer("load", "URL");
  ```
- To retrieve *active page*:

  ```
  $("#foo").pagecontainer("getActivePage");
  ```

Comment: The last document I reviewed before posting this question was one of yours "https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6865#issuecomment-31394184", and thank you for that and the detailed explanation here. I just have a few questions on this. Even in the other link I've refered in this comment, you have used `$(document).on('pagecontainerhide',function(){...});` why have you used the `$(document)` selector?

Comment: @Lordbalmon [`document`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) is [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) object that holds all HTML. From it, you can access all HTML elements which are present into DOM. Another note, `.pageContainer` is different than [_pagecontainer events_](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/).

Comment: Aah, I get it, so when you used the `$(document)` to bind the event using `on()`, you were actually binding it to the `pagecontainer` but accessed through `$(document)`. Am I correct?

Comment: @Lordbalmon Exactly. Those events are emitted and then _delegated_. However, not all of them can be delegated. Please check the link in my previous comment. Also, this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20459433/1771795) will give you some insight.

Comment: Thank you @Omar, just one thing, so in the entire documentation for Pagecontainer in the official jquerymobile page, when they refer to `$('.selector')`, its the selector for the page container which could either be delegated through the `document` or `body` (if using the default option) or `:mobile-pagecontainer` is that right?

Comment: @Lordbalmon No, you have to differntiate between $(`document`) and `$(".selector")`. The former holds all HTML nodes that can be accessed via JS. The latter is an _element_ you want to target. jQM documentation has used `$(".selector").pagecontainer()` in case a different _parent / wrapper_ is used other than `body`. For events, you need `$(document)`, however, inside it, you can bind events directly to an element, e.g. `$("#foo").on("click", ...`.

Comment: the same I meant but poorly phrased in my excitement :), Thank you Omar, this answers my question completely.

Comment: @Lordbalmon Sorry, maybe I've misunderstood you. You're welcome! I'm glad I've been of help :)