# JQuery Mobile Components in React

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, dom, reactjs

"JQuery Mobile Components in React"

I'm quite new to this concept an still need to figure things out. I built an app for mobile purposes and decided to wrap it in React components. My Code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>shounds</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.squareui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <script src="./ext/react.js"></script>
    <script src="./ext/jsx-transform.js"></script>
    <script src="//fb.me/react-with-addons-0.11.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-theme="e">
    <div id="container" >
        <!--<div data-role="page" id="login"><div data-role="header" id="loginHeader"></div></div>-->
    </div>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="./comp/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js //react components

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return Page({id: 'login'});
    }
})

var Page = React.createClass({
    constants: { dataTheme: 'e' },
    render: function () {
        return React.DOM.div({ id: this.props.id + 'Page', 'data-role': 'page', 'data-theme': this.constants.dataTheme },
            Header({ dataTheme: this.constants.dataTheme, id: this.props.id }))
    }
})

var Header = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return React.DOM.div({'data-role': 'header', 'data-theme': this.props.dataTheme, id: this.props.id+'Header' })
    }
})


// Render application.
    React.render(App(null), document.getElementById('container'))
```

The DOM gets created in the container div as expected.

Heres my Problem:

JQM probably isnt aware of the virtual DOM getting created by React and creates an initial page by itsself outside the container div. 
Even though the DOM is created correctly it wont be displayed as JQM page with Header.

Anyone gone through the same stuff?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: if it helps in any way -> this is what is created during runtime

```
    <head></head>
    <body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-a" data-theme="e">
        <div class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active" data-role="page" data-url="/E:/dev/workspace/visual/shounds/index.html" tabindex="0" style="min-height: 483px;">
            <div id="container">
                <div id="loginPage" data-reactid=".0" data-theme="e" data-role="page">
                    <div id="loginHeader" data-reactid=".0.0" data-theme="e" data-role="header"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="./comp/main.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1. you need to set `#container` as _pagecontainer_ 2. disable auto-initializing and do it manually once your page is added to DOM 3. can you setup a fiddle?

Comment: 1. why should i rename #container to pagecontainer? 2. how can i do this? I thought about doing this - but simpy cant find it in the JQM Docs 3. I have allot of other dependencies but ill get one up asap. 4. is the jqm rendering going to interfere with my react rendering in any other point?

Comment: 1. because pagecontainer by default is `body`, you have to override this. 2. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24173950/1771795 3. thanks, i'm trying to setup one too 4. it depends, I dont know the way React works.

Comment: Okay first of all thanks for the answer - I will try to get this to work and set up a Fiddle with the working code. Just watched a video from pete hunt where a related question is asked quite at the end of his presentation (40 mins) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgVS-zXgMTk I'll check this out...

Comment: I managed to get it running now! setting the pagecontainer on mobileinit was enough. Maybe im just lucky though and it just renders its DOM elements faster than JQM. I should definitly add manual initialization

Comment: didn't work without auto-init disabled http://plnkr.co/edit/gZPjmOurvio6NRIQpZex?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

Apply the following styles to remove extra height in page and make it fit *viewport*, since *pagecontainer* is no longer `body`.

```
.ui-mobile body {
  height: auto; /* reset height */
}
#container {
  height: 99.9%; /* new viewport (pagecontainer) */
}
```

---

First step, you have to inform framework (jQuery Mobile) that you want to use a different *pages wrapper* (`:mobile-pagecontainer`) than the default `body`. Also, you should disable *auto-initialization* of jQuery Mobile's until *React* renders the page and push into DOM. Those steps should be executed on `mobileinit` which is the first event that fires before jQuery Mobile is initialized. Also, note that is should be placed after jQuery Core and before jQuery Mobile in `head`.

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function(e, data) {
  $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false; /* disable auto-initialization */
  $.mobile.pageContainer = $("#container"); /* set new "pagecontainer" */
});
```

After that, run your *React* code followed by `$.mobile.initializePage();` to initialize framework.

> **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ymF5I5H4VXaLajyEWTx7?p=preview)**

Comment: like I said in the comment above.. didnt need to handle the initilization, but that is probably just due to react randomly loading quicker on my Device -> I will add the manual initialization now. Thanks so far - great help!

Comment: @MaxBumaye You're welcome. Try it with auto-initialization, it should work. Edit: on plunker it didn't work without disabling auto-init. http://plnkr.co/edit/gZPjmOurvio6NRIQpZex?p=preview

Comment: thanks for the update - probaby $.mobile.initializePage(); should also go in the components "componentDidMount" event to trigger when the component loaded the DOM

Comment: @MaxBumaye it's a jQM error `.ui-mobile body { height: 99.9%; }` it should be `.ui-mobile .ui-mobile-viewport` because `body` isn't always pagecontainer. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/7841

Comment: @MaxBumaye `auto` is better than `0`.