# unsupported pseudo: mobile-pagecontainer

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to setup a function `beforeshow` on a page container.  Reading the jquery mobile docs.  The API docs describe:

```
$( ".selector" ).pagecontainer({
   beforeshow: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

I have no idea what the `.selector` refers to in the API docs (the docs are quite confusing in their usage of `.selector`).  However I have found a post suggesting that `:mobile-pagecontainer` can be used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24173950/1033422

I have created the following:

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer({
   beforeshow: function( event, ui ) {
      ...
   }
});
```

But this results in:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 
   unsupported pseudo: mobile-pagecontainer
```

I'm using jquery mobile 1.4.5.

Comment: have you tried $.mobile.pageContainer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was because I was trying to bind to a jquery mobile event before jquery mobile was initiated.

Moving `$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer()` inside a `pageinit` function fixed the issue for me:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#settings", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer({
           beforeshow: function( event, ui ) {
              ...
           }
      )};
)};
```