# Redirect Jquery mobile to new page with triggering of functions in this page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am building a mobile app, using JQuery mobile, and in the front page let's call it page-1 contains navigation buttons to different pages let's call one of them page-2

Below are page-1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").pagecontainer({
        defaults: true
    });

    $("#page-2").click(function () {
        $("body").pagecontainer("change", "page-2.html", {
            reload: true
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function_in_page - 2.init();
        });
    });
```

page-2 has the following

```
var function_in_page = {
    init: function () {
        alert('first-1');
        $("#button-1").click(function () {
            alert('second-1');
        });
    });
```

So what is happening that I get the alert of "First-1" but when I click the button with ID (button-1) nothing happens , any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `.pagecontainer()` is *auto-initialized* with default settings, so you don't need to initialize it.

Secondly, refrain from using `.ready()` to add listeners in jQuery Mobile and stick to *pagecontainer events* instead. The latter events are fired whenever jQM framework loads a page and/or navigates to it via Ajax, especially in *Single Page Model*. Unlike `.ready()` which fires one time only when framework is initialized.

There are many methods to control your webapp using jQuery Mobile in a *Single Page Model* using *pagecontainer events*. The safest way is to give each page a *unique ID* in order to determine which event is omitted on which page. Another note, you need to know that no matter how many *external pages* you have, only two pages will remain in DOM; *homepage* and another *external page* you have navigated to from *homepage*.

To add listeners, use `pagecreate` event, it is equivalent to `.ready()` and can be delegated to specific pages.

```html
<div data-role="page" id="home">
```

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#home", function () {
   $(".selector").on("click", function () {
      /* run code */
   });
});
```

That event will fire once per page, but note that it will fire again on any *external page* loaded via Ajax. Therefore, you should remove previous bindings before adding new ones, by using `.off()`. Otherwise, attached listeners will multiple whenever you load an *external page* via Ajax.

```html
<div data-role="page" id="second">
```

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#second", function () {
   $(".selector").off("click").on("click", function () {
      /* run code */
   });
});
```

Keep all your custom JS code in `head` of all pages, although the code will be loaded once in first run. jQuery Mobile loads first *page div* of each *external page*, anything outside that div is entirely neglected.

---

Back to your code above, here is how it should look like. Give each page an ID, and use them to add `click` listeners. Let's assume `home` is homepage and `second` is page-2.html.

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#home", function () {
   $("#btn").on("click", function () {
      $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "page-2.html");
   });
});
```

Now, page-2.html is visible. Add a `click` listener to `button-1`.

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#second", function () {
   $("#button-1").off("click").on("click", function () {
      alert("page 2");
   });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tOs4ErLoh5f0YJqqoeTc?p=preview)**

[Read more about *pagecontainer events*.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20459433/1771795)

Comment: +1 thanks omar, it solved my problem, I am little bit confused by this new approach but trying to understand it , but I am facing another problem, for example when I being redirect to page 2, some time it flash me back to where I came from?

Comment: Salam @MohamedMostafa can you post another question with all details and code?

Answer (score -1):

If the script in page-2 is executed to early the button might not exist yet. Try wrapping it in a `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var function_in_page={init:function(){
   alert('first-1');
    $("#button-1").click(function(){
    alert('second-1');
    });});
});
```