# Jquery mobile, init bind page events only once

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile v1.3.2

For some reasons I want to set an global `pagechange` event to prepare all of my pages :

```
var Front = {

    initDom : function($dom) {

       // here i can bind some events in my page

       $(".someButton",$dom).bind("tap",function(){
           alert("some actions");
       });

       // etc.....

    });

}

$(document).on("pagechange", function(event, data) {     
    Front.initDom($(data.toPage));
});
```

This works well. But it is triggered at each page change. And some times it will init the same event twice and that will lead to some bugs.

Now i have tested to do it with the event `pageinit` or `pagecreate` but both are triggered before the page is ready and `$("ui-page-active");` is empty.

I have though about some setTimeout, but that's definitively a bad idea.

I have also though to init everything at the first `pageinit` and unbind it. But ajax called page wont be bound.

It there some good workarround ?

Comment: If you want to do something once to first page and only when DOM is ready, use `.one("pagebeforeshow")` or `pageshow`. To add bindings/attach listeners, use `pageinit` delegated to page by its' ID.

Comment: Yes it would work, but i'm doing this globally. For all the pages. Not only for certain pages.

Comment: it depends on what you want to do. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20459433/1771795

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pageinit and then get the id of the page from the event target object:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function(e){
    alert(e.target.id);
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/e50nb4hL/)**

Comment: This is exatly what i needed !